# Drag and Drop vbox element with show snapshot in javafx

Tags: drag-and-drop, javafx-2

I want drag an element in vbox as a parent and show node moving during drag and drop of element, how can do this with The slightest change.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit? Are you dragging data from one control to another (such as dragging an item from one ListView to another), or are you just wanting to reposition a node by dragging it around?

Comment: no just drag node from vbox and insert in different row of vbox

Answer (score 6):

Just register mouse listeners with the elements of the VBox. You want to call startFullDrag() on the node on a dragDetected event, and rotate the child nodes of the VBox on a dragReleased event. You can use the dragEntered and dragExited events if you want to give visual hints to the user about the drag.

See the [API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/MouseDragEvent.html) for more.

Simple example (code is way cleaner in JavaFX 8, btw):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseDragEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            final VBox root = new VBox(5);
            final ScrollPane scroller = new ScrollPane();
            scroller.setContent(root);
            final Scene scene = new Scene(scroller,400,200);

            for (int i=1; i<=20; i++) {
                final Label label = new Label("Item "+i);
                addWithDragging(root, label);
            }

            // in case user drops node in blank space in root:
            root.setOnMouseDragReleased(new EventHandler<MouseDragEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(MouseDragEvent event) {
                    int indexOfDraggingNode = root.getChildren().indexOf(event.getGestureSource());
                    rotateNodes(root, indexOfDraggingNode, root.getChildren().size()-1);
                }
            });

            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void addWithDragging(final VBox root, final Label label) {
        label.setOnDragDetected(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                label.startFullDrag();
            }
        });

        // next two handlers just an idea how to show the drop target visually:
        label.setOnMouseDragEntered(new EventHandler<MouseDragEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseDragEvent event) {
                label.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #ffffa0;");
            }
        });
        label.setOnMouseDragExited(new EventHandler<MouseDragEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseDragEvent event) {
                label.setStyle("");
            }
        });

        label.setOnMouseDragReleased(new EventHandler<MouseDragEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseDragEvent event) {
                label.setStyle("");
                int indexOfDraggingNode = root.getChildren().indexOf(event.getGestureSource());
                int indexOfDropTarget = root.getChildren().indexOf(label);
                rotateNodes(root, indexOfDraggingNode, indexOfDropTarget);
                event.consume();
            }
        });
        root.getChildren().add(label);
    }

    private void rotateNodes(final VBox root, final int indexOfDraggingNode,
            final int indexOfDropTarget) {
        if (indexOfDraggingNode >= 0 && indexOfDropTarget >= 0) {
            final Node node = root.getChildren().remove(indexOfDraggingNode);
            root.getChildren().add(indexOfDropTarget, node);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats good,tanx, but i want show node snapshot with mouse moving during drag and drop, like moving a node in scene builder, but just in vbox.

Comment: That's a bit more work, but not too bad. In the dragDetected listener, create an image by taking a [sanpshot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#snapshot-javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters-javafx.scene.image.WritableImage-) of the dragging node. Create an ImageView from the image and call `setManaged(false)` on it, and add that to the VBox. Register a mouseListener with the VBox that calls `relocate(...)` on the ImageView when the mouse is dragged. In the dragReleased, remove the image view and the listener from the VBox.

Comment: Also, in Java 8, if you start a full drag and drop (rather than the "full press-drag-release" in the example above), you can set a drag view on the Dragboard. This might be easier, but it feels like a full drag and drop is not really appropriate as you are just moving nodes, not transferring data around your app.

Comment: Superb answer. This should be marked as the answer. Mean while, I will post @James_D suggestion in the comment as an answer - which shows how to show a snapshot of the draggable node

Comment: How could I do some clean up after the MouseDragEvent is done und the mouse button for dragging has been released? I mean, if I do it in `root.setOnMouseDragReleased` then it will only be applied if the release happend within the application's thresholds.

Answer (score 3):

This is an addendum to [@James_D's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22838363/952511)

This shows how to add an image preview to the draggable node as @James_D suggests in his comment:

```
     private void addPreview(final VBox root, final Label label) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(label.snapshot(null, null));
        imageView.setManaged(false);
        imageView.setMouseTransparent(true);
        root.getChildren().add(imageView);
        root.setUserData(imageView);
        root.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                imageView.relocate(event.getX(), event.getY());
            }
        });
    }

    private void removePreview(final VBox root) {
        root.setOnMouseDragged(null);
        root.getChildren().remove(root.getUserData());
        root.setUserData(null);
    }
```

Call `addPreview()` in `label.setOnDragDetected()`. Call `removePreview()` in `label.setOnMouseDragReleased()` and `root.setOnMouseDragReleased()`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a much better solution that is far cleaner now.

```
// Root is the node you want to drag, not the scene root.
root.setOnDragDetected(mouseEvent -> {
    final ImageView preview = new ImageView(root.snapshot(null, null));

    final Dragboard db = root.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY);
    db.setContent( // Set your content to something here.
    );
    db.setDragView(preview.getImage());

    mouseEvent.consume();
});
```

Comment: This is completely different then [the answer @james_d gave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22838363/952511), and it doesn't at all cover dragging or dropping children in VBoxes.