# How to drag children outside of parent layout JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, drag, mousepress

Hi and thanks in advance for any advice.

Basically I have a flowpane as the content of a scrollpane for showing a user Buttons containing data. I need to be able to drag these anywhere on the screen but the buttons clip at the edges of the scrollpane. I use this code for dragging the buttons:

```
dataButton.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
            nodeCoordinates[0] = e.getSceneX() - dataButton.getTranslateX();
            nodeCoordinates[1] = e.getSceneY() - dataButton.getTranslateY();
            dragData = data;
        });
dataButton.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
            dataButton.setTranslateX(e.getSceneX()-nodeCoordinates[0]);
            dataButton.setTranslateY(e.getSceneY()-nodeCoordinates[1]);
        });
dataButton.setOnMouseReleased(e -> {
            dataButton.setTranslateX(0);
            dataButton.setTranslateY(0);
            if(e.getButton().equals(MouseButton.SECONDARY)){
                openDataPanel((Credential) data);
            }
            DragClearer clear= new DragClearer();//An extension of Thread for nulling a drag variable I have which gets filled with the respective data when the button is dragged
            clear.start();
        });
```

the flowpane is what contains each button and the scrollpane doesnt take up the entire screen there are other things displayed. I need the buttons to return to their original position unless they are dragged to specific areas which they do. A while a go i did use the in-built dragging and dropping but didnt really work for what I needed it to. I would say im an intermediate at javaFX so my knowledge doesnt really go that far. And when searching online I havent really found anything similar to my problem so im either doing something wrong or im definetly doing something wrong.

Again any advice you guys can give is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example that hopefully can get you in the right direction.

This code takes a snapshot of the node and then sets the node invisible. The snapshot is draggable to any part of the `Scene`. On release on a target node, the Button is recreated using information from the original button. I haven't tried it, but I would guess that on release on a target node, you can add the button as a child to the target node.

I altered the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55709991/2423906). @James_D answer may be better from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22838363/2423906). I did not try his code.

### Main

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * Demonstrates a drag-and-drop feature.
 */
public class App extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {
        //Source Buttons.
        final Button boat1 = new Button("boat1");
        final Button boat2 = new Button("boat2");
        final Button boat3 = new Button("boat3");
        final Button boat4 = new Button("boat4");

        //Adding OnDragDetected to source Buttons.
        setOnDragDetected(boat1);
        setOnDragDetected(boat2);
        setOnDragDetected(boat3);
        setOnDragDetected(boat4);

        //Adding onDragDone to source Buttons.
        setOnDragDone(boat1);
        setOnDragDone(boat2);
        setOnDragDone(boat3);
        setOnDragDone(boat4);

        //Creating GridPane
        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
        gridPane.setVgap(5);
        gridPane.setHgap(5);
        gridPane.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
        gridPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black;");
        //Adding StackPane to every Cell in the GridPane and Adding the Target Events to each StackPane.
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
            stackPane.setPrefSize(150, 50);
            stackPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow;");
            setOnDragOver(stackPane);
            setOnDragEntered(stackPane);
            setOnDragExited(stackPane);
            setOnDragDropped(stackPane);

            gridPane.add(stackPane, i / 3, i % 3);
        }

        HBox root = new HBox(new VBox(boat1, boat2, boat3, boat4), gridPane);
        stage.setTitle("Hello Drag And Drop");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 200);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    //source events handlers
    public void setOnDragDetected(Button source)
    {
        source.setOnDragDetected((MouseEvent event) -> {
            /* drag was detected, start drag-and-drop gesture*/
            System.out.println("onDragDetected");
            final ImageView preview = new ImageView(source.snapshot(null, null));
            
            /* allow any transfer mode */
            Dragboard db = source.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY);

            /* put a string on dragboard */
            ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
            content.putString(source.getText());
            db.setContent(content);
            db.setDragView(preview.getImage());
            source.setVisible(false);
            event.consume();
        });
    }

    public void setOnDragDone(Button source)
    {
        source.setOnDragDone((DragEvent event) -> {
            /* the drag-and-drop gesture ended */
            System.out.println("onDragDone");
            /* if the data was successfully moved, clear it */
//            if (event.getTransferMode() == TransferMode.MOVE) {
//                source.setText("");
//            }

            event.consume();
        });
    }

    //target event handlers
    public void setOnDragOver(StackPane target)
    {
        target.setOnDragOver((DragEvent event) -> {
            /* data is dragged over the target */
            System.out.println("onDragOver");

            /* accept it only if it is  not dragged from the same node
            * and if it has a string data */
            if (event.getGestureSource() != target
                    && event.getDragboard().hasString()) {
                /* allow for both copying and moving, whatever user chooses */
                event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY_OR_MOVE);
            }

            event.consume();
        });
    }

    public void setOnDragEntered(StackPane target)
    {
        target.setOnDragEntered((DragEvent event) -> {
            /* the drag-and-drop gesture entered the target */
            System.out.println("onDragEntered");
            /* show to the user that it is an actual gesture target */
            if (event.getGestureSource() != target
                    && event.getDragboard().hasString()) {
                target.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green;");
            }

            event.consume();
        });
    }

    public void setOnDragExited(StackPane target)
    {
        target.setOnDragExited((DragEvent event) -> {
            /* mouse moved away, remove the graphical cues */
            target.setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow;");

            event.consume();
        });
    }

    public void setOnDragDropped(StackPane target)
    {
        target.setOnDragDropped((DragEvent event) -> {
            /* data dropped */
            System.out.println("onDragDropped");
            /* if there is a string data on dragboard, read it and use it */
            Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
            boolean success = false;
            if (db.hasString()) {
                //target.setText(db.getString());
                Button tempBoat = new Button(db.getString());
                tempBoat.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
                target.getChildren().clear();
                target.getChildren().add(tempBoat);
                success = true;
            }
            /* let the source know whether the string was successfully
            * transferred and used */
            event.setDropCompleted(success);

            event.consume();
        });
    }    
}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: I think this could be what I'm looking for. If the snapshot is draggable anywhere on the scene then it could definetly work for me. I have two buttons. A bin and a decryption one and the idea is you drag the Hutton over these buttons, and letting go will either delete the data and the button, or decrypt the data and send the button back to its original place. I'll try it out soon and let you know how it goes. Thank you for the code example

Comment: I took the idea of a snapshot and set it as the cursor image when being dragged, and then resetting the cursor image when "released". Definetly on the right track just fine tuning it. Thanks for the idea